# Thou came here for a rest

Tags: riddle

> Thou came here for a rest.
>   With my body, I made a shelter
>   Thou feel so cool, when I flutter
>   Thou touch me with his finger
>   didn't know whether it hurts me
>   And I get some sketches but feel real
>
> And Thou fly away
>   All my wings are caused to sway
>   That one last touch hurts me enough
>   My one finger goes down to lay.

Who/what am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is:

> Tree

Thou came here for a rest.

With my body, I made a shelter

> Bed and other furnitures are made of wood

Thou feel so cool, when I flutter

Thou touch me with his finger

didn't know whether it hurts me

And I get some sketchs but feel real

> In cold winds, you burn a log with match-stick and don't care if it hurts the wood to get warmth. Fire -> real

And Thou flies away

All my wings are caused to sway

> When a glider or an plane passes, it causes the leaves to sway

That one last touch hurts me enough

My one finger goes down to lay.

> "one last touch" with an axe causes the tree's "one finger" (trunk) to lie down. Thanks [randal'thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/12042/answer-who-what-am-i/12045?noredirect=1#comment36977_12045) for this.

Comment: the last one a splinter in your finger? it doesn't really fit but... :P

Comment: "one last touch" with an axe causes the tree's "one finger" (trunk) to lie down?

Comment: @randal'thor A big thanks, this connects the last piece of puzzle

Comment: Reading this reminded me of The Giving Tree by Shel Silverstein.

Comment: Well you've got the right answer!  "TREE" @MohitJain

Answer (score 3):

The answer is

> Caterpillar/ Butterfly (A Butterfly Life cycle)

Thou came here for a rest--

> caterpillar comes to rest and builds a cocoon around it.

With my body, I made a shelter ---

> "pupa" is the transformation stage within which the caterpillar tissues are broken down and the adult insect's structures are formed.

Thou feel so cool, when I flutter --

> Feels cool when it tries and fly

And I get some sketchs but feel real--

> Beautiful colors on the wings of the butterfly.

My one finger goes down to lay---

> The butterfly lays eggs

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! 
Please explain your answer, how did you come out with this solution?

Comment: Also don't forget that touching butterfly wings prevents them from flying. I was also thinking that "My one finger goes down to lay" refers to the butterfly leaving it's cocoon (which looks like a finger) and it disintegrates.

Comment: @leoll2 It's really cool #PuzzlingSE... I like people thinking about my answer! It's TREE! I made it by some pieces of a poet(a poem I read from long long ago).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is right, but maybe on the right track. Are you:

> A fan

Thou came here for a rest. 
With my body, I made a shelter

> People like sitting near fans and they normally have a protective cage around them

Thou feel so cool, when I flutter

> When a fan is on, it can cool you down

Thou touch me with his finger 
didn't know whether it hurts me

> Some people like to risk putting their fingers along a fan and might get hurt

And I get some sketchs but feel real

> I guess some fans can have special designs/sketches

And Thou fly away
All my wings are caused to sway

> Some fans can blow you away (Like in air tunnels)

That one last touch hurts me enough 
My one finger goes down to lay.

> You can turn fans off with the push of a button